# time.sleep(3) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I scrape the websites in list by using selenium. Then, the TypeError always occurs when strat the third loop (urls3). What the problem is? and How can I fix it?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

title =[]
links = [url1, url2,..., urln]
for link in links:

  driver = webdriver.Chrome("\\chromedriver.exe")

  driver.get(link)

  page_html = driver.page_source
  time.sleep(60)
  data = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

  jobtitle = data.findAll('h1', {'class':'topcard__title'})
  for job in jobtitle:
    title.append(job.text)
  driver.close()
```

Comment: did you import "time"?

Comment: Yes, already imported

Comment: @davbuc That would raise a `NameError`. @OP Are you sure that the error comes from the `time.sleep` line? You say it happens when you _start_ the third loop iteration. Please include the actual stack trace in your post as well.

Comment: @bnaecker Sorry, it happens in the second loop Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 35, in <module>
    time.sleep(60)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: why you think that exception goes from above code?

Comment: The code you have cannot cause that error. That would require code that somehow does `setattr(time, "sleep", None)`, which nothing seems to do. Please make sure you post a complete, reproducible example.

Comment: Do you have your own file named `time.py` in the current directory?

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan I don't know why  but previously it can run without problem

Comment: @JohnGordon I don't have it but the previous implement I can run time.sleep()

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import time; print(time.__file__)`

Comment: @JohnGordon import time; print(time.__file__)
AttributeError: module 'time' has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I can implement it without time.sleep().

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue to this while attempting to add `time.sleep()` inside of a block of code for my issue it was some thing like this throwing the error.

```
from roku import Roku
roku = Roku('192.168.43.20')
from get_audio import get_audio
from voice import speak
import time

def search_tv(text):
    text = text.replace("search","")
    roku.search()
    print("this is search_tv def block" + text)
    roku.literal(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.select()
```

Now the solution to my issue was `time.sleep()` was recognized in the beginning of my scripts within def for some reason it wasn't importing.

I solved my issue by adding import time within the loop itself. as shown below

```
from roku import Roku
roku = Roku('192.168.43.20')
from get_audio import get_audio
from voice import speak

def search_tv(text):
    import time
    text = text.replace("search","")
    roku.search()
    print("this is search_tv def block" + text)
    roku.literal(text)
    time.sleep(2)
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.right()
    roku.select()
```

I have not been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the error being thrown. I do believe that this issue has something to do with the size of data in the memory blocks with possibly python not thinking that import time should have priority?